# Why does wmic report another SID than whoami /user?

Tags: windows, sid

When I execute `whoami /user` on the command line, I get

```
User Name             SID
===================== ==============================================
tq84\rene.nyffenegger S-1-5-21-1111111111-2222222222-3333333333-1224
```

However, If I execute `wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid`
I get a different SID:

```
S-1-5-21-4444444444-5555555555-6666666666-1001
```

Not only is the RID different, but also the figures that are supposed to identify the domain.

Is this behaviour expected or is something gone wrong with the SID database on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the domain (or computername for local accounts)

```
wmic useraccount where "Domain='%userdomain%' AND name='%username%'"
```

Comment: This reports `No Instance(s) Available`, probably because I am disconnected from the domain controller. I need to check again tomorrow when my computer is connected again.

Comment: Now that I am connected to the DC, I get the same SIDs with your query.